# Group by with MAX() still selects other row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I'm writing a query where I need to select student name by who has a `MAX` `gradelevel_id`. How ever it still selects the other row with the same id of the student where I already define what `gradelevel_id` should I select.

```
schoolyear_id | student_id | gradelevel_id
 407            18            307
 409            18            309`
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
student_mt.student_id, 
registration_mt.firstname, registration_mt.middlename, registration_mt.lastname,
MAX(grade.gwa)

FROM schoolyear_student_lt

INNER JOIN gradelevel_mt ON gradelevel_mt.gradelevel_id = schoolyear_student_lt.gradelevel_id
INNER JOIN student_mt ON student_mt.student_id = schoolyear_student_lt.student_id
INNER JOIN registration_mt ON registration_mt.registration_id = student_mt.registration_id
INNER JOIN student_grade ON student_grade.student_id = schoolyear_student_lt.student_id
INNER JOIN grade ON grade.grade_id = student_grade.grade_id

WHERE gradelevel_mt.gradelevel_id = 309

GROUP BY student_mt.student_id;
```

If I define **307** in my `WHERE CLAUSE` still selects the student name which I should not already see in my row.

Output:

`student_id | firstname | middlename | lastname | MAX(grade.gwa)
     18         Billie        Joe       Armstrong      88`

Comment: why not include registration_mt.firstname, registration_mt.middlename, registration_mt.lastname in your GROUP BY?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

*(This is more of a comment)* I guess you accidentally stumbled on the quirky MySQL behavior of `GROUP BY`.

When using `GROUP BY`, in the `SELECT` clause we can only put the `GROUP BY` predicate (`student_mt.student_id`) and aggregate functions (`MAX(grade.gwa)`). Even though MySQL allows this, the DBEngine assumes you know what you are doing but might result in anomalies.

Why not get take the approach of getting the `student_id(pk)` for the `MAX(grade.gwa)` as a inner sub query and then do the `INNER JOIN`'s with other tables to select what you wanted in the outer subquery.